# Делаю backup винта через dd. В итоге sha1sum не совпадают

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование, sha1, gzip

Добрый день.

Cуть проблемы: после создания образов с одного и того же ssd ssd_1.img.gz, ssd_2.img.gz ... ssd_n.img.gz их sha1sum не совпадают.

Бакапы делаю так:

```
dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=8M | gzip -c  > /path/to/backup.img.gz
```

P.S. Все бакапы делаю не перезагружая live usb linux на другой винт.

[Disk cloning](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_cloning)

UPD:

Почему проверочные сумы не совпадают?

Раздел /dev/sda не примонтирован. Разве туда что-то может писаться?

Возможно я не правильно пользуюсь dd?

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: ...

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1026048   1107967     81920    40M unknown
/dev/sda3    1107968   1370111    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1370112   2906111   1536000   750M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5    2906112 485691391 482785280 230.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  485691392 500116143  14424752   6.9G Windows recovery environment

# mount
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3864908k,nr_inodes=966227,mode=755)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755)
/dev/sdb on /run/archiso/bootmnt type iso9660 (ro,relatime)
cowspace on /run/archiso/cowspace type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=262144k,mode=755)
/dev/loop0 on /run/archiso/sfs/airootfs type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/dev/mapper/arch_airootfs on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=22,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /etc/pacman.d/gnupg type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=775504k,mode=700)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc3 on /mnt type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: в чём заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, sha1sum не совпадают. Так и должно быть? Как тогда проверить бакап на целостность?

Comment: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос. и не забудьте уточнить, с какой именно целью вы используете именно такие параметры для программы `dd`. внести исправления в вопрос можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: А как насчёт вывода `mount`?

Comment: @andreymal, вывел mount

Comment: сейчас пробую с bs=512

Comment: Пробуйте без gzip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подумал надо вашей проблемой. Причину вижу только одну - SSD сыпется. Попробуйте методом половинного деления найти проблемную область.

То есть сделать пару бекапов не всего SSD а только первой половины и проверить контрольные суммы. Если не совпадают сделать бекап четверти объема и т. д.

Может даже лучше попробовать начать с небольшой какой-то части и посмотреть что будет. Если хеши не совпадут, попробуйте проверить без упаковки образов.

**Добавлено:**

Дополните `gzip` ключем `-n` иначе в архив добавляется дата, время и имя файла. То есть должно быть так:

```
dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=8M | gzip -cn > /path/to/backup.img.gz
```

Comment: Хм, проверил сжатие `123456` gzip'ом — хэш меняется каждую секунду. Так что, видимо, ответ в последнем предложении

Comment: да это скорее всего источник проблемы. спасибо! сейчас попробую.